# Yodlee User password reset

Tags: yodlee

I am using Yodlee aggregation api's and i was wondering if there is a way to reset password for an existing user without knowing the current password ? The API Documentation says that a user can only be unregistered if userId/password are known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the below set of API's which will help you to reset the password of any existing user without knowing their password.However you should have a valid co-brand login and registered user id.

### Password Rest Management Service APIs:

Step 1. Get the token by calling `getToken` API.

Step 2. Get the token specific user context from `getPasswordResetUserContextFromToken` API by passing token got from step 1.

Step 3. Set the session by calling  `setSessionForValidToken`  API by passing token got from step 1 and user context from step 2.

Step 4. Now call the `changePassword` API by passing token got from step 1 and user context from step 2 and new credentials.

---

1.Service Name: `PasswordResetManagement`
 Operation: `getToken`

Sub URL: `/jsonsdk/PasswordResetManagement/getToken`

API Parameters:
`cobSessionToken`   Valid Cobrand Session Token
`Username`  Valid user name

Sample API Response:

```
{"validUntil":"2014-05-23T18:15:16+0530","username":"yodlee121","token":"364cb1d62f8380b7f3596e73f2179b4d"}
```

2.Service Name: `PasswordResetManagement`
 Operation: `getPasswordResetUserContextFromToken`

Sub URL: `/jsonsdk/PasswordResetManagement/getPasswordResetUserContextFromToken`
API Parameters:
`cobSessionToken`   Valid Cobrand Session Token
token `364cb1d62f8380b7f3596e73f2179b4d`

Sample API Response:

```
{"conversationCredentials":
  {"sessionToken":"06142010_0:f7cf401c5e7404b8fecd47fe340c69168c411dd966fe12906fedafecd71e7af6832a9585dc283f268a0989a9c50999d1027156fc83bd64285c37a8d839ed4a82"},
  "valid":false,
  "isPasswordExpired":false,
  "cobrandId":10000004,
  "channelId":-1,
  "locale":"en_US",
  "tncVersion":2,
  "applicationId":"17CBE222A42161A3FF450E47CF4C1A00",
  "cobrandConversationCredentials":
    {"sessionToken":"06142010_0:a6c2ab5ff19c8cad89d7aef58474e191a54e81607bff5e2257c7d98b1d985d29c685ccbf2fe032f2c6fe1c7fddff36acd18c5ac20ee3f4676d5c76b3e6b7a3a9"},
  "preferenceInfo":{"currencyCode":"USD","timeZone":"PST"}
}
```

3.Service Name: `PasswordResetManagement`
 Operation: `setSessionForValidToken`

SERVICE URL:`/jsonsdk/PasswordResetManagement/setSessionForValidToken`
API Parameters:
`cobSessionToken`   Valid Cobrand Session Token
`userSessionToken`  Password reset user session token
token `364cb1d62f8380b7f3596e73f2179b4d`

Sample API Response:

```
{}
```

4.Service Name: `PasswordResetManagement`
 Operation: `changePassword`

SERVICE URL:`/jsonsdk/PasswordResetManagement/changePassword`
API Parameters:
`cobSessionToken`   Valid Cobrand Session Token
`userSessionToken` Password reset user session token
token `364cb1d62f8380b7f3596e73f2179b4d`
`newCredentials.objectInstanceType` com.yodlee.ext.login.PasswordCredentials
`newCredentials.password`   New password

Sample API Response:

```
{"loginName":"raja12345","password":"raja@12345"}
```

Comment: Second "getToken" parameter is "username" (lowercase) and not "Username".

Comment: Do you know where I can see a reference of the these explanations on Yodlee's apidocs? Which are the specific urls to be called, the http methods, the possible errors, etc