# How to actually reset Yodlee user password

Tags: php, yodlee

Coming from this question

[Yodlee User password reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399887/yodlee-user-password-reset)

I see it is thoroughly explained theoretically how to reset Yodlee user's password.

I, however, can't find anything on Yodlee's apidocs.

I am stuck on step 2 (already managed to get a token following this explanation: https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/user/getToken)

What I am asking is can someone show me where I can see the actual urls to be called, the HTTP methods, the possible exceptions, etc...

Where are this service called `PasswordResetManagement` and the mentioned in the answer above operations explained/ documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the web service `/{cobrandName}/v1/user/credentials` to reset the password. See https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/user/updateCredentials.